# How to establish ssh key pair when "Host key verification failed"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, foreign-keys

I have set up ssh key pairs between my desktop and two servers, and from the servers to my desktop, but after reinstalling the OS on my desktop, I can't re-establish the key-pair going into my desktop by this:

```sh
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t 
ssh-copy-id username@server
```

I get the following error:

(names in *italics* changed to protect the innocent My desktop is Ubuntu, and I can't find the answer  [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys))

> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
> @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
> IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
> Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle
> attack)!
> It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
> The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
> *ab:cd:ef:gh*
> Please contact your system administrator.
> Add correct host key in /home/*user*/.ssh/known_hosts to get
> rid of this message.
> Offending key in /home/*user*/.ssh/known_hosts:1
> RSA host key for *user.server* has changed and you have requested strict
> checking.
> Host key verification failed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58169386/4393351

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The problem occurs if the host key has expired or been altered (for example, a new install on the server side), so it no longer matches the key in your `known_hosts`

You can delete the key(s) currently associated with the host and attempt to SSH once more. This ensures both the client and server recognize the new key.

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname
```

This deletes the offending key from the `known_hosts`

The man page entry reads:

> `-R hostname` Removes all keys belonging to hostname from a known_hosts file. This option is useful to delete hashed hosts (see the -H option
> above).

Comment: i have this same problem, but legitimately.  my laptop moves between two networks (home and work) and there are overlaps.  i need to ssh to machine A when i'm at work and machine B when i'm at home, but both machines have the same ip address.  is it possible to keep both as valid entries in my known_hosts file despite the ip address conflict?

Comment: +1
"Host key verification failed" means that the host key of the remote host was changed.

Ssh stores the host keys of the remote hosts in ~/.ssh/known_hosts. You can either edit that text file manually and remove the old key (you can see the line number in the error message), or use

ssh-keygen -R hostname

Comment: NOTE: run the command on you local machine rather than the remote server. OR you can open `~/.ssh/known_hosts` on your local machine and delete the line manually.

Comment: man ssh-keygen:  -R hostname
             Removes all keys belonging to hostname from a known_hosts file.             This option is useful to delete hashed hosts (see the -H option             above).

Answer (score 19):

Most likely, the remote host ip or ip_alias is not in the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file. You
can use the following command to add the host name to known_hosts file.

`$ssh-keyscan -H -t rsa ip_or_ipalias  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Also, I have generated the following script to check if the particular ip or ipalias is in the know_hosts file.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Jason Xiong: Dec 2013   
# The ip or ipalias stored in known_hosts file is hashed and   
# is not human readable.This script check if the supplied ip    
# or ipalias exists in ~/.ssh/known_hosts file

if [[ $# != 2 ]]; then
   echo "Usage: ./search_known_hosts -i ip_or_ipalias"
   exit;
fi
ip_or_alias=$2;
known_host_file=/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts
entry=1;

cat $known_host_file | while read -r line;do
  if [[ -z "$line" ]]; then
    continue;
  fi   
  hash_type=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/|/ /g'| awk '{print $1}'); 
  key=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/|/ /g'| awk '{print $2}');
  stored_value=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/|/ /g'| awk '{print $3}'); 
  hex_key=$(echo $key | base64 -d | xxd -p); 
  if  [[ $hash_type = 1 ]]; then      
     gen_value=$(echo -n $ip_or_alias | openssl sha1 -mac HMAC \
         -macopt hexkey:$hex_key | cut -c 10-49 | xxd -r -p | base64);     
     if [[ $gen_value = $stored_value ]]; then
       echo $gen_value;
       echo "Found match in known_hosts file : entry#"$entry" !!!!"
     fi
  else
     echo "unknown hash_type"
  fi
  entry=$((entry + 1));
done
```

Comment: This worked for me. I am using a CI and I want to SSH with Deployer/Envoy, so I needed to add the host first.

Answer (score 5):

Step1:$Bhargava.ssh#

> ssh-keygen -R 199.95.30.220

step2:$Bhargava.ssh #

> ssh-copy-id hostname@199.95.30.220

```
          Enter the the password.........
```

step3: Bhargava .ssh #

> ssh hostname@199.95.30.220

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-68-generic x86_64) * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/ Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS server : 228839 ip : 199.95.30.220 hostname : qt.example.com System information as of Thu Mar 24 02:13:43 EDT 2016 System load: 0.67 Processes: 321 Usage of /home: 5.1% of 497.80GB Users logged in: 0 Memory usage: 53% IP address for eth0: 199.95.30.220 Swap usage: 16% IP address for docker0: 172.17.0.1 Graph this data and manage this system at: https://landscape.canonical.com/ Last login: Wed Mar 23 02:07:29 2016 from 103.200.41.50
```

hostname@qt:~$

Comment: Thanks! But is this any different than the existing [answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8506473/199217)?

Answer (score 4):

If you're **sure** the server is correct, `sed -i 1d ~/.ssh/known_hosts` will delete line 1 of your local `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.  The new correct key will be added to the file the next time you connect.

Comment: Nice solution. But doesn't this assume that the server in question (my desktop in this case) was first line in the file? I found that "ssh-keygen -F hostname" tells the line that the hostname key is on, so presumably sed -i nd ~/.ssh/know_hosts would work if n were the line number'

Comment: @David: The output you pasted above says "Offending key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1".  You know what the line number is already, don't have to run `ssh-keygen -F`.

Comment: I didn't realize that was what the number was... thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Also sometimes there is situation when you are working on serial console, then checking above command in verbose mode `-v` will show you /dev/tty does not exists, while it does.

In above case just remove /dev/tty and create a symlink of /dev/ttyS0 to /dev/tty.

Answer (score 2):

Its means your remote host key was changed (May be host password change),

Your terminal suggested to execute this command as root user

```
$ ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R [www.website.net]:4231
```

You have to remove that host name from hosts list on your pc/server. Copy that suggested command and execute as a root user.

```
$ sudo su                                                            // Login as a root user

$ ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R [www.website.net]:4231   // Terminal suggested command execute here
Host [www.website.net]:4231 found: line 16 type ECDSA
/root/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /root/.ssh/known_hosts.old

$ exit                                                               // Exist from root user

$ sudo ssh root@www.website.net -p 4231                              // Try again
```

I Hope this works.

Answer (score 2):

This issue arises when the host key is expired or changed. you can remove the keys that host is using and try to ssh again, so that you are adding new key that is known to both client and server.

You can check the keys associated with your hosts with `cat /.ssh/known_hosts` . Now, You can remove the hosts keys manually or using the ssh-keygen option. You can do either of the following option.

1. Manual removal of keys

   vim /.ssh/known_hosts

delete the key that is associated with your host.

2. Remove key using ssh-keygen

   ssh-keygen -R your_host_or_host_ip

This will remove your key associated with the host.

Now, you can ssh to your host as usual and you will be asked if you want to continue to this host. Once your enter yes, this host will be added to your/.ssh/known_hosts with updated key. By now, you should be your host.

Answer (score 1):

First you should remove existing key. SSH keys in most of Linux-based OS will be saved this file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts", so in order to remove the key related to host the following command will be used:

`ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R [Hostname]`

Regards
K1

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -f /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts
```

or open it up and delete the entry for the offending ip/hostname

(P.S. It tells you exactly this in the error message you posted)

Comment: I had tried this but deleted the files from the host (my desktop) instead of the guest (the server that I had logged into from my desktop). Thanks for the reminder...

Comment: You don't have to delete the whole file…

Comment: @ephemient: that is duly noted right after the example of how to delete the whole file ;) I opened up the known_hosts file on my computer and it looked pretty cryptic to me. I do like your answer. Just looks like i slightly beat you to the punch!

Comment: @ephemient Also I would be curious to know if you know of any instances where deleting the whole file would have disadvantages other than the little warning the (next) first time you try to connect to an IP that was in known_hosts. Could it actually break anything or is it just a slightly annoying warning?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to connect your remote server with ssh:

```
$ ssh username@ip_address
```

then the error raise, to solve it:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f "/home/local_username/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "ip_address"
```

Answer (score -1):

Task Passwordless authentication for suer.

Error : Host key verification failed.

Source :10.13.1.11
Target : 10.13.1.35

Temporary workaround :

[user@server~]$ ssh user@10.13.1.35
The authenticity of host '10.13.1.35 (10.13.1.35)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is b8:ba:30:46:a9:ab:70:12:1a:f2:f1:61:69:73:0a:19.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.13.1.35' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

Try to authenticate user again...it will work.