# Git checkout failed with exit code: 1 in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, sonarqube

I have setup code in Azure DevOps Repository. I am using a self-hosted agent for pipelines. I have set up a pipeline to use Azure DevOps repository, but in the checkout, I'm getting below error.

I have tried by cleaning the work folder. Also, I have added `"IgnoreCase=True"` in specific work's config file.

```
##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
##[debug]Finished process 14976 with exit code 1, and elapsed time 00:00:13.4575355.
##[error]Git checkout failed with exit code: 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Git checkout failed with exit code: 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]
##[debug]   at Agent.Plugins.Repository.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext executionContext, RepositoryResource repository, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Agent.Plugins.Repository.CheckoutTask.RunAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext executionContext, CancellationToken token)
   at Agent.PluginHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I want checkout Azure DevOps Repository using a self-hosted agent.

Comment: You'd better updated with **sharing the completed log**. Until now, these log are too board to analyze. In addition, did your repos has submodule?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Yes repos have submodule. But when I am using "Azure Pipelines" agent at the time I am not getting any error in checkout.

Comment: Got it, the submodule should be the issue caused. Could you mind share the full debug log?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Full Log will contain some confidential information So I can not share it. But it's fine if I will use "Azure Pipelines" agent, but when I am using this agent then in SonarQube Analysis I am getting a proxy error. "
Agent job 1: "[SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"ETIMEDOUT","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"XXXXXX","port":XXX}"" If you can help in this thing it will grate for us. In summary our goal is to run sonar analysis from Azure DevOps Pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> at
>   Agent.Plugins.Repository.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext
>   executionContext, RepositoryResource repository, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)

According to this error message, I check its corresponding source function code: [GetSourceAsync](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/src/Agent.Plugins/GitSourceProvider.cs#L220). Then from comment I confirmed that this repos has submodule. So this issue caused by did not enable `Checkout Submodule` optional before build.

According to the Checkout log shared privately:

[image]

The value of `checkoutSubmodules` is `False`, this is why the agent could not install the project which contain submodule, and throw the error message.

To solve it, just go Get Source page, then **enable** the optional: **Checkout submodules**:

[image]

Comment: that I did. [debug]checkoutSubmodules=True ##[debug]checkoutNestedSubmodules=True

Comment: Still, git checkout failed and getting below error. 
error: unable to create file "xxxxxxxxxxx" Filename too long

Comment: @ankitthakkar,This is another error, which is the default limit in private agent. You'd better shorten the file name.

Comment: @ankitthakkar Hi, if this helped, you can accept this answer, so other SO users can refer to this solution work.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Any idea on what to do when the nested submodules are not checked out, some warning about access rights - how to actually make sure Azure Agent is having all the rights?

Comment: @serup, can you please share the error message you faced? It is clear for me to provide you the exact suggestions~

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I made it work by adding a token url in the .gitmodules file - then checkout of nested submodules works

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue since yesterday,

[image]
(Image is showing the error: clone of 'git@ssh....' into submodule path 'c:/...' failed)

**Solution:**
I was using SSH keys, I have changed that to the https url of my sub module repository. and re-ran the pipeline, and it worked.

What I did is, I opened my `.gitmodules` file, and and updated the url from `'git@.....'` to the https url of my sub module repository, `' https://'`, as shown below:

**Old File: (using SSH Keys)**

```
[submodule "submodules/confluenceCloud"]
    path = submodules/confluenceCloud
    url = git@xxx.azure.com:kushalseth/confluenceCloud
```

to

**New File: (using HTTPS)**

```
[submodule "submodules/confluenceCloud"]
    path = submodules/confluenceCloud
    url = https://kushalseth@xxx.azure.com/kushalseth/confluenceCloud
```